# Opinion on data passing between SQLite and MySql db.

Tags: android, mysql, json, sqlite

I am making an Android App for marking Attendance of students. I have an SQLite database in the app and a MySql remote database. The app sends and receives data between the two databases and i am thinking of using JSON for parsing data. Is there any other method for parsing data between the databases other than JSON that is more efficient and good. Thanks! Cheers!

Comment: see this for JSON:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25208654/how-do-i-connect-mysql-database-and-insert-data-into-it-using-android-code/25209458#25209458

Comment: BTW: you do not "use JSON for pasing data". JSON is data format, so you can "parse JSON for data" at most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a plethera of other data choices other than JSON.

JSON has the advantage of being easy to read, which makes debugging the wire protocol easier. It can be kind of verbose though, and there are more compact encodings which will save bandwidth.

I personally really like [Avro](http://avro.apache.org/). However, other good choices are [Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/) and [Protocol Buffers](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/). All three offer a way to convert POJOs into a compact binary form. Thrift is basically a redo of protocol buffers by guys that were hired away from Google by Facebook. Avro takes a slightly different approach in that it has Schema resolution, which can make some schema evolution tasks easier to accomplish.