# sending Location Data from Android to a MySQL Database

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I created an Android app that takes a photo and collects the location at the time photo is taken, I want to send this data to a server (Backend) and store it in a Database. Can GAE be used for the purpose of sending and storing this data?

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25408822/connect-mysql-with-android/25409204#25409204

Answer (score 0):

Yes GAE can.
In GAE you can chose to develop your backend in Java, Python, PHP angd GO. It gives to you the possibility to use both a SQL database and a google custom database that follows a non relational scheme (The Datastore).
Thus you can send via HTTP the data you want to your GAE web app and process or store them in the serverside.