# How to connect mySQL in my android project?

Tags: php, android, mysql

is there a way to integrate directly mySQL in my Android project without using php. How can I do it or can I have any tutorials on the topic? If that isn't possible how to make a connection between Java and PHP.

Comment: Do you want to use MySQL client-side, on the Android device ? Same thing for PHP ?

Comment: Use sqlite3 for storing data on the local side. And if you want to store your data at server side use BAAS (Backend as a service) like parse from Facebook. There is no way to interact directly with mysql from your phone.

Comment: http://capdroid.wordpress.com/2012/07/10/configuring-and-accessing-mysql-jdbc-driver-on-android-application/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Connect mySQL through json parsing

**here are some examples**

[Connect mySQL with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25408822/connect-mysql-with-android/25409204#25409204)

[Sending ArrayList from Android to PHP script using JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582199/sending-arraylist-from-android-to-php-script-using-json)

[How do i connect mysql database and insert data into it using android code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25208654/how-do-i-connect-mysql-database-and-insert-data-into-it-using-android-code/25209458#25209458)

**Diagrammatic Representation**

[image]

Edit: http://www.trustingeeks.com/connect-android-app-to-mysql-database/