# Sending JSON data to PHP

Tags: java, php, android, json

I'm trying to send JSON data over to a PHP service. This is the code that I have to transmit the data over:

```
public class TransmitRegistrationData extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, JSONObject, JSONObject> {

    String url = "http://kreationware.com/phpimp/RegistrationDataReceiver.php";

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(JSONObject... data) {
        JSONObject json = data[0];
        try {

            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppostreq = new HttpPost(url);
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
            se.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json;charset=UTF-8"));
            httppostreq.setEntity(se);
            HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppostreq);

        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            return json;

    }
}
```

And I'm populating and building said JSON data as such

```
public void buildRegistrationData(String data){
        try{
            jsonObject.put("registration_data", data);
            registrationJsonObject.put("registration_information", jsonObject);
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Where **String data** is what the user inputs. Yet I keep receiving an empty array on the PHP side. Any clue where I'm going wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26124087/how-to-connect-mysql-in-my-android-project/26124751#26124751

Answer (score 0):

Two thing, first you should use the magical library [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to mapping your JSON Objects. Second, in my experience you should send your JSON strings in Base64 representation to avoid encoding issues. 
I preffer use [Volley](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley/) HTTP library when I need send data to a server.